# How Can I Make All Navigation Links in JoomGallery Specific to the Component's Root Category?

Tags: php, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

In this art website I'm working on for a school project, I am using Joomla 1.5 as the CMS of choice and JoomGallery to display artworks. *(I tried to install 1.6 several times, but the "Next" buttons would not work for me for some reason. I installed it manually, but had another issue, so finally reverted to 1.5... and then I realized that the "other" issue was easily fixed. I'll migrate it to 1.6 eventually, but not now.)*

On the website, there are three primary categories of art, all of which appear in the menu--Traditional, Digital, and Photography. Each one is linked to a respective category in JoomGallery, each with its own subcategories.

What I want in this case is that each one is locked within its own boundaries, essentially. However, when clicking on the "Last Added" and "Most Viewed" links, images are taken from EVERY SINGLE category I have created and is published, not just the current "root" category I set for the page and its sub-categories. Additionally, I'd like "total number of hits" and "total images" to be restricted to that specific category and its sub-categories.

I searched around and I could not find a way to fix this. I'm sure there's a way, but I'm not too keen on Joomla yet... I've tried looking into it and I can't figure out. I just naturally assumed that this would be pretty obvious--if I set a category in a Menu Page, all the links and everything would be restricted to that single category, but its not the case, and I don't like it.

I know there's got to be a way to do this, but again, I'm really not into Joomla much yet. I managed to build the template from scratch (with a tiny bit of help from tutorials), but I haven't started getting into other Extensions yet. How can I go about accomplishing this task which should have been an option to begin with?

Below is a link to the website. Again, the pages I'm referring to are Traditional, Digital, and Photography. The categories are locked down pretty good (can't view any higher/other categories), but the TOP links don't restrict it by category, and neither do the total number of hits/images.

http://aeternalwings.tsr-online.org

And no, I don't hate JoomGallery... in fact, its the best free Open Source Joomla Gallery I've found, and I doubt I'll find a better one without having to pay an arm and a leg. Its mainly this one thing that's bothering me.

*P.S. The artwork on this site is not mine, but I DO have permission to use it. This website is for my fiance, and all artwork was drawn by her, and all photos were taken by her (except for perhaps the self-portrait displayed on the "Blog" page). It was built during a school assignment, and she will later use it once it is complete.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If JoomGallery is not set up to display like you want then it's going to be a pretty major task to change it. In order to get the images to filter the way you want you will need to edit the SQL queries in the model to take the current category in to account.

Comment: I can edit the SQL queries easy enough... the problem is that I don't know all the functionality that goes into JoomGallery, and I don't know where its located. Namely, I don't know the variables and that kind of data that is processed, so it'll be a bit of a problem trying to figure out how to do that.

I was just hoping that someone here knew about JoomGallery... I figured I'd get answers here easier from people that actually use it.

Comment: Assuming it is coded in Joomla MVC, you will need to look in the model files. Read through the Joomla MVC tutorial to get an idea of how it should work - http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1

Comment: Took me FOREVER to figure out how to do it... but I finally got it working... ugh...